# Will another site (a shop in shop) that shows our inventory then directs users to us to complete the purchase hurt our SEO?

Tags: seo, ecommerce

My company has build a webshop (for jewels and watches in case that matters). We got contacted by another site, a shop-in-shop.

**The shop-in-shop site does the following:**

- Collects feeds from different shops and present those products **(1)**
- You can browse those products per category, similar products sorted together
- When you click a product, you get a 'preview', a fancybox-like div with img and a price **(2)**
- When you click `buy` they redirect the user to the productpage of the webshop offering it

*(1) I don't know how they decide to show which product if multiple shops offer the save, asume all shops provide unique products*
*(2) It's not an iframe, so it's not a subpage or something (in case of duplicate content)*

I'm worried this might backfire, but a.t.m. I can't really think of something that will effect negatively, and the increase in backlinks and pagevisits is positive.

Comment: By thinking about several seconds, I don't find any pitfall either unless your RSS feed contains content of your pages (possible duplicate content issues).

Comment: They don't show product descriptions I believe. Even if they do, they display it all in one page (in the source), so it's not the same. I can't find any downsides so far, but I dont want to be surprised

Answer (score 1):

The main concern would be duplicate content.   If the pages at both sites are the same and the other site could be more authoritative, then they could rank for your content.   There are two reasons that it shouldn't be a big issue:

1. They don't show product descriptions, so that is still unique to your site
2. The buy button links back to your site.   A link to the original source of content is a signal that Google uses to determine which site is the duplicate.